# How to group checkboxes so that only one can be checked between the groups

Tags: android, checkbox

I got a layout which contains a `RecyclerView`. Its list items contains a checkbox. There are about 10 list items, and I need to be able to group them such that the first check box is a group on its own, the 2nd and 3rd checkbox are another group, and the rest of them are unrelated and can be checked freely.

What it means is that if the first checkbox is checked (i.e from the first group), the 2nd and 3rd (i.e the second group) should be unchecked. The 2nd and 3rd boxes can be checked together or separately, but then the 1st check box must be unchecked. All the rest of the boxes can be checked or unchecked freely and are unrelated to the groups in mention.

I can only access the check boxes through the `public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position)` of the adapter since like I said, they are a part of a list item.

Is there a way to make it smarter than using the position of the item?

Comment: From a UX perspective, IMHO this is not a good use of checkboxes, as users will not expect that checking a checkbox will change data in other widgets. Enabling/disabling widgets based on a checkbox is reasonable.

Comment: @Yonatan Nir Could you please show your output so that the problem can be understand easily.

Comment: @CommonsWare its funny since you're actually pretty right about that. In my case, the first check box says "i don't use a device". The 2nd says "I use device A" and the 3rd says " I use device B". It's obvious that the 1st check box is redundant, but I have to add it.

Comment: Consider using `RadioButton`. While you may not be able to use a `RadioGroup` to manage the mutual-exclusion, at least it fits the desired UX. Beyond that... I'm not sure why you are using a `RecyclerView` here. If there are only 10 items, and few/none are the same, I'm not sure that `RecyclerView` is giving you much value over a `ScrollView` wrapped around a traditional layout.

Comment: A radio button doesn't fit here. I need the concept of a group of check boxes. the 2nd group got several check boxes which can all be checked